# Find unmatched records from columns (Union) Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the records that doesn't match between two columns.

I have this query:

```
select iNum 
from doc_file_fs 
where iNum not in 
(select iFile from doc_client_fs)
union (select iFile from doc_employee_fs)
union (select iFile from doc_prov_fs)
UNION (select  iFile from doc_soc_fs)
UNION (select  iFile from doc_cor_fs)
```

but only find the one from the first select and not the other unions...

Please, i need help and i'm new here, be patient if the question is not well formed :C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to write the query like this:

```
select iNum 
from doc_file_fs  df
where not exists (select 1 from doc_client_fs dc where df.iNum = dc.iFile) and 
      not exists (select 1 from doc_employee_fs de where df.iNum = de.iFile) and 
      not exists (select 1 from doc_prov_fs dp where df.iNum = dp.iFile) and 
      not exists (select 1 from doc_cor_fs ds where df.iNum = ds.iFile) and 
      not exists (select 1 from doc_employee_fs de where df.iNum = de.iFile) and 
      not exists (select 1 from doc_cor_fs dc where df.iNum = dc.iFile) ;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on `ifile` on each of the other tables.  This should be much, much faster than the version using `union` and `not in`.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do the trick?

```
SELECT iNum 
FROM doc_file_fs 
WHERE iNum NOT IN 
(SELECT iFile FROM doc_client_fs
UNION
SELECT iFile FROM doc_employee_fs
UNION
SELECT iFile FROM doc_prov_fs
UNION
SELECT iFile FROM doc_soc_fs
UNION
SELECT iFile FROM doc_cor_fs)
```

I suppose that your issue is in placing `UNION` outside brackets.